# Drive API V3: wrong filesize on multiple-chunks resumable upload, using Google Apps script (2 bytes missing)

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, youtube-data-api

I have a Google apps script web-app that downloads the data associated with any Youtube channel's videos and save the result in a .CSV on the user's Google drive. Here are the main steps of the code:

1. A GAS function (named "X") is called when the user click on a button inside his browser (using google.script.run). It queries the Youtube API within a loop that stops when the nextPageToken is null or when the function has been running for approximately 330 seconds (because the max allowed runtime for a function is 6 minutes in GAS). While doing so, for each video, I create a CSV string that I push inside an array (thus I have an array of arrays, let's call it "mainArr").
2. When X successfully stops, it returns mainArr and another function (named "Y") is called, whose aim is to start uploading "Utilities.newBlob(mainArr.join('\r\n'))" on the user's Drive, chunk by chunk (size of each chunk is 256kb, except for the last one, as per [the doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/resumable-upload)).

Now here is my issue: when X gets all the videos, everything is nicely uploaded on Drive. But if I reduce the running time of X (48 seconds for instance) and calls it several time (as well as Y) to get all the videos, a CSV is created which misses 2 bytes (on bytes per iteration, it seems). Thus, instad of 576,845 bytes obtained with just one run of X and Y, I get (576,845 - (number of run of Y) * 2) bytes. That is problematical, because it means I'm missing some videos in my .CSV (I checked that).

So far, I limited the fields downloaded to the videos'IDs, to be sure that the size difference is not caused by some update of the data (for instance, the number of views of the videos is regularly increasing). I also checked that the function creating the chunks from mainArr does not corrupt the data. It does not.

A final note, on how I am calling X and Y multiple times: when X returns, Y is called, and uploads mainArr chunk by chunk, except for the last one (named "lastChunk"). When it is done working, it empties mainArr (mainArr = []), and returns mainArr as well as the base64encoded lastChunk. Then X is called another time. It feeds the emptied mainArr with some new data, and returns, passing mainArr and the encoded lastChunk. Y is called, the bytes of lastChunk and mainArr are concatenated, the result is then uploaded chunk by chunk. And so forth.

Excerpt of Y, to highlight a part of what has just been described:

```
var csv = Utilities.newBlob(mainArr.join('\r\n'));
if (lastChunk) {
  csv = Utilities.newBlob((Utilities.base64DecodeWebSafe(lastChunk)).concat(csv.getBytes()));
}
var chunkSize = (256*1024); //as per the drive doc,
var fileBytes = csv.getBytes();
var fileSize = fileBytes.length
var chunksCount = Math.ceil(fileSize / chunkSize)
for (var i = 0; i < chunksCount; i++) {
  var chunk =  csv.setBytes(fileBytes.splice(0, chunkSize))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"While doing so, for each video, I create a CSV string that I push inside an array" -> I pushed the bytes of my CSV string instead of the CSV string itself, and everything works.